# Need help onTouch Event

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I am programming a little application for a school project : the concept is simple : A song is played while circle pop randomly on the screen during a brief moment and the users have to click on the screen to gain points.

I found this code for the circle which is working fine :

```
public class Partie extends AppCompatActivity  {

RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new SplashLaunch(this));
}

public class SplashLaunch extends View {

    Handler cool = new Handler();
    ObjectAnimator aa = new ObjectAnimator();
    Paint newPaint = new Paint();
    int randomWidthOne = 0;
    int randomHeightOne = 0;
    private int radiusOne = 150;
    final int redColorOne = Color.RED;
    final int greenColorOne = Color.GREEN;
    private int lastColorOne;
    private final Random theRandom = new Random();

    public SplashLaunch(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private final Runnable circleUpdater = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lastColorOne = theRandom.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColorOne : greenColorOne;
            newPaint.setColor(lastColorOne);
            cool.postDelayed(this, 1500);  // Time between each circle to pop on the screen
            int x = 0;
            while (x <= 200) {  // x = transparency : 0 ==> non visible  , 255 ==> visible
                newPaint.setAlpha(x);
                x++;
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        cool.post(circleUpdater);
    }

    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        cool.removeCallbacks(circleUpdater);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (theRandom == null) {
            randomWidthOne = (int) (theRandom.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth() - radiusOne / 2)) + radiusOne / 2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs((getHeight() - radiusOne / 2 + radiusOne / 2f))));
        } else {
            randomWidthOne = (int) (theRandom.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth() - radiusOne / 2)) + radiusOne / 2f);
            randomHeightOne = (theRandom.nextInt((int) Math.abs((getHeight() - radiusOne / 2 + radiusOne / 2f))));
        }
   } } }
```

So, my question is : how do I implement the onTouch event on Circle whose position constantly change ? Or do I need to think of another method like defining an invisible button at the center of the circle when he pops up ?

I found this to use the onTouch event but I don't really understand how to implement it in my case :

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        switch (me.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                x = me.getX();
                y = me.getY();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I am a beginner so any help will be welcomed :).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you may want `SplashLaunch circle = new SplashLaunch(this);` followed by `circle.setOnTouchListener` in the Activity